# implementation of component did mount in stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Im new to react, i'm trying to implement/learn stateless component, Im having difficulty in using component will mount in stateless component.

My code

```
const Terms = (actions, commonReducer) => {
componentDidMount() {
    actions.userActions()
}

return (
    <div className="jobUpdate">

        <form onSubmit={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault(); actions.userInput(document.getElementById('enteredVal').value)
        }}>
            <input type="text" id="enteredVal" />
            <button type="submit"></button>
        </form>


    </div>
);
```

};

I know the stateless component does not have life cycle hooks, but wanted alternate approach to preform component did mount in stateless component.

Any help with this is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: In redux, data travels down so your component should only be affected by its props - why would it need a `componentDidMount()` as the only changes will be caused by prop changes, causing a re-render anyway?

Comment: Basically, the question shouldn't be 'how can I implement lifecycle hooks in redux?', it should be 'how can I change my code to match Redux and remove the need for lifecycle hooks'?

Comment: @BenKolyaMansley how to trigger redux action from my component? could you provide some example to help me understand better

Comment: You need a function like `mapDispatchToProps()` which gives the component access to dispatching particular actions using props - read [this guide](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could always wrap the component in another component, using a pattern known as **higher-order components**.

> A [higher-order component (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) is a function that takes a component and returns a new component.

Perhaps the most widely used example of this technique is [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux), which uses the connect() method to create components connected to the redux store.

Instead of creating your own HOC, there are also libraries out there that can do it for you, such as [react-redux-lifecycle](https://github.com/mpeyper/react-redux-lifecycle).

**However**, what you are attempting with this component is not a very common pattern -- **it is much more common to instead keep the handling of business and data in a *container* component, and leave *presentational* components to inherit store actions and data from props**. Check out Dan Abramov's [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) for a very good overview on how and why to break down components into these two categories!

Answer (score 1):

Starting in React 16.8, you can accomplish the same kind of functionality using a `useEffect` hook.

In your specific example, we'd have something like this:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

// other imports and declarations

function Example() {
  // Similar to componentDidMount 
  useEffect(() => {
    // This function will be run on component mount
    myAction();
  }, []); // The second argument of [] tells react to only perform the effect on mount

  return (
    <div>
      ... your component
    </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) do a great job of explaining this, and I'd encourage you to read up on it. Keep in mind that it's not exactly the same thing going on behind the scenes, and so the patterns will not be a one-to-one correspondence; but these patterns should help with the majority of your cases.

Just know the following basic ideas:

1. The first argument of a `useEffect` hook is a "side effect" function. It is always run after the first component's render, and then conditionally afterwards.
2. This "side effect" function can return a "cleanup" function. The "cleanup" function is run just before the next time the "side effect" function is run. It will always be run before unmounting the component.
3. The second, optional, argument of a `useEffect` hook is an array of dependencies.
4. If any value in the dependency changes, the "side effect" function will be run after the next render.

Anyway, in the meantime, here's a few patterns to emulate class component behavior.

### componentDidMount + componentDidUpdate

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("This line will be run after each render ");
});
```

### componentDidUpdate when a given value changes

```
// get myValue from component props
const { myValue } = props;

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("This line will be run after each render where myValue changed");
}, [myValue]);
```

### componentDidUpdate when a given value changes, pt. 2

```
// get myValue from component props
const { myValue } = props;

const myCondition = myValue === "yes";
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('This line will be run after each render where the returned value of the statement `myValue ===  "yes"` changes from false to true or true to false ');
}, [myCondition]);
```

### componentDidUpdate when a given value changes, pt. 3

```
// get myValue from component props
const { myValue, myValue2 } = props;

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("This line will be run after each render where myValue OR myValue2 changed");
  
}, [myValue, myValue2]);
```

### componentDidMount

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("This line will be run only after the first render ");
}, []);
```

### componentWillUnmount

```
useEffect(() => {
  // nothing will be run as a side effect...
  return () => {
    // but this will be run as clean up
    console.log("This line will be run just before the component unmounts");
  };
}, []);
```

### componentDidUpdate (without componentDidMount)

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

export default function MyComponent() {

  // create a reference value which does not trigger a re-render when changed
  const isMounted = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if( isMounted.current === false ){
      // on mount, set the ref to true
      isMounted.current = true;
    } else {
      // the component is already mounted
      console.log("This line will be run after each render except the first ");  
    }
  }); 

  return (<div />);
}
```

Hope this will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Throw a dumb work around using HOC (high order component)

```
const withLifecycles = (MyStatelessComp) => class extends React.PureComponent {
   static propTypes = {}
   static displayName = "withPure(xxx)"
   state = {}
   componentDidMount() {}
   render() {
      return <MyStatelessComp {..this.state, ...this.props} />
   }
}
```

then use it as

```
MyStatelessWithLifecycles = withLifecycles(props => {    
  ...    
  return <Bla /> 
}
```

Though not sure what's the reason for a stateless component to have the lifecycles there, it's meant to be pure and simple (presentation only).